# XSLFGroupShape does not encompass its child shapes

Tags: java, apache-poi, xslf

I'm using Apache POI 3.16 (the latest version at the time of writing). In the following snippet, I create a XSLFGroupShape which I then use to create a bunch of child shapes:

```
XSLFGroupShape group = slide.createGroup();

XSLFAutoShape cardRect = group.createAutoShape();
cardRect.setShapeType(ShapeType.RECT);
cardRect.setAnchor(rect);

XSLFPictureShape avatarShape = group.createPicture(avatar);

// More shapes added to the group here...
```

The problem is the following: in the generated PowerPoint file, the group position and dimensions appear to be uninitialized (I've selected the rectangle whose content is pixelated; the whole rectangle and its content is a single XSLFGroupShape; notice the group's manipulator at the top-left corner of the slide):
[image: PowerPoint Screnshot showing a group's manipulator being uninitialized]

Am I missing anything in my code? Is there a way to circumvent or fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GroupShape` needs an `Anchor`and an `InteriorAnchor`. And the grouped shapes must fit into the `GroupShape`. The `PowerPoint` GUI does managing that automatically while the user is working with groups. But `apache poi` needs correct settings for this since it simply writes into the file what the program says.

Example: A group shape in width 350, height 300, left 100, top 50 and a simple shape in each of it's corners.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;

public class CreatePPTXGroupShape {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  Slide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

  int groupLeft = 100;
  int groupTop = 50;
  int groupWidth = 350;
  int groupHeight = 300;
  int groupPadding= 10;

  GroupShape group = slide.createGroup();
  group.setInteriorAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft, groupTop, groupWidth, groupHeight));
  group.setAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft+groupPadding, groupTop+groupPadding, groupWidth-groupPadding, groupHeight-groupPadding));

  AutoShape shape = group.createAutoShape();
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeType.RECT);
  shape.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
  shape.setAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft, groupTop, 150, 100));

  shape = group.createAutoShape();
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeType.TRIANGLE);
  shape.setFillColor(Color.RED);
  shape.setAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft+groupWidth-120, groupTop, 120, 100));

  shape = group.createAutoShape();
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeType.DONUT);
  shape.setFillColor(Color.YELLOW);
  shape.setAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft, groupTop+groupHeight-90, 90, 90));

  shape = group.createAutoShape();
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeType.ELLIPSE);
  shape.setFillColor(Color.BLUE);
  shape.setAnchor(new Rectangle(groupLeft+groupWidth-100, groupTop+groupHeight-100, 100, 100));

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreatePPTXGroupShape.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```