# Apache Poi create group of images

Tags: java, apache-poi

In powerpoint there is a nice feature that allows you to choose "group" from the context menu when selecting more than one object. See a example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SsLS.jpg).

Currently I have created a slide and a image like this:

```
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();


byte[] pictureData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputstream);

XSLFPictureData pd = ppt.addPicture(pictureData, PictureData.PictureType.PNG);
XSLFPictureShape picture = slide.createPicture(pd);
```

Is there a way to incorporate that feature via the apache poi into my current code?

Comment: I'm guessing XSLFGroupShape, as used in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109882/xslfgroupshape-does-not-encompass-its-child-shapes

Comment: If you'd like to post that as the answer it is the solution!